# What php config setting would make file_get_contents not read http/url files?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Recently on a LAMP server file_get_contents stopped reading http files(generated with php on the same server) but it reads html files in the same directory. Html files are on the same server.

Any ideas what might have changed in PHP, Apache or any other configurations?

**More details**
The code was reading some pages that were generated by a CMS eg: http://example.com/a-page. In essence the url is an http://example.com/index.php?q=a-page that is configured to redirect properly using .htaccess commands

**Managed to find the error**

`Error:     file_get_contents(http://example.com/site-configuration/footer.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

  Error type/ Nr.:  Warning - 2

  File:     /var/www/websites/example/assets/snippets/footer/footer-bug.php

  Line:     11

  Line 11 source:   $output = file_get_contents('http://example.com/site-configuration/footer.html');`

Apache/2.2.14
PHP Version 5.2.11

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean  by "stopped"? Is the problem local or remote? I.e. is PHP/Apache not sending the requests, or is the remote server not responding correctly?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - I was able to generate the footer of a page reading another  page in the CMS that was designed to be a footer. I was using file_get_contents. It stopped working yesterday and broked the site. It started working again at 8am this morning. No idea what it was. Also see my comment to CBroe + the error I forgot to add above

Answer (score 0):

It's a setting called [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Comment: Not sure that is it: allow_url_fopen in ON, allow_url_include is off

Comment: You might have to elaborate on "file_get_contents stopped reading http files but it reads html files".  What do you mean by "http files" and how are you distinguishing from "html files"?

Comment: I added some details. I think it stopped reading php files that generate html

Answer (score 0):

If it was any of the `allow_url_*` settings, you should get a warning telling you about it. Make sure you have proper `error_reporting` enabled. If that’s the case, and you still don’t get a warning, then that’s likely not it.

You need to investigate more thorough what “stopped working” *actually* means. Maybe it makes the request, but gets an HTTP error code in response? That will make a “pure” `file_get_contents` return just `false`.

Use

```
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

after your `file_get_contents` call to see what response the last HTTP request made returned.

You can also pass a `context` to `file_get_contents`, so that it will return the response body even if the response headers indicated an error.

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'ignore_errors' => '1'
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: I added the error above, the weird part is that it started working again at 8am. It was not working at 7:55 but it was working at 8:02. I believe there is some caching layer or some sort of cron job that might have fixed the problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It started working again. I was told it was the log bouncer(not sure what this is)